# Find unique elements and increment count

Tags: java, arraylist, logic

I have a class called ResourceObject

```
public class ResourceObject
{
    int id;
    String Name;
    int count;
}
```

For this class, i've overridden the `equals` method such that the objects are equal if only the `id` and `name` are same.

Now i ve a list of `ResourceObject` objects `List<ResourceObject> resList.`

Lets say the contents are

```
id   name   count

1    A      1
1    A      2
1    A      1
2    B      1
2    B      2
3    C      2
```

All I want to do is find the unique List and increment the count. i.e, the result should be

```
id   name   count

1    A      4
2    B      3
3    C      2
```

How do i do it? Thank You.

Comment: i had tried. and i also got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I got the solution.

`List<ResourceObject>` originalList is the list containing original elements

```
List<ResourceObject> newList=new ArrayList<ResourceObject>();

for(int i=0;i<originalList.size();i++){
    if(newList.contains(originalList.get(i))==false){
        newList.add(originalList.get(i));
    }
    else{
        for(int j=0;j<newList.size();j++){
            if(newList.get(j).equals(originalList.get(i))){
                int var=newList.get(j).getCount();
                int var1=var+originalList.get(i).getCount();
                newList.get(j).setCount(BigDecimal.valueOf(var1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the `List` and add elements to a `Set` if the `Set` doesn't contain the element , if the `Set` already has the element , get the element from the `Set` and increase its `count`.

At the end of the loop , you can convert the `Set` to a `List` if required.

Comment: this is just logic! I did it without having to use the set!

Answer (score 0):

Well, just as an idea in pseudocode.

```
for(ResourceObject o : resList) {
    int count = sumAllCounts(o);
    saveCountAndObjectSomewhere(o, count);
}
showResults();
```

Of course this will show you several lines for each of the equal objects, but you can get rid of the duplicates by putting them in a Set for example.